# Ubuntu 13.04 MySQL won't start

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

My main SolusVM Node / OpenVZ Node needed a reboot today out of the blue and a kernel upgrade. So we finished that then on a couple of the VPS units for some reason MySQL won't start after the reboot. This is just some of the VPS units, not all of them.

The error in `/var/log/mysql/error.log` is the following:

```
140415 11:12:29  InnoDB: Error: io_setup() failed with EAGAIN after 5 attempts.
InnoDB: You can disable Linux Native AIO by setting innodb_use_native_aio = 0 in my.cnf
140415 11:12:29 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot initialize AIO sub-system
140415 11:12:29 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140415 11:12:29 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140415 11:12:29 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140415 11:12:29 [ERROR] Aborting

140415 11:12:29 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140415 11:12:30 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140415 11:12:30 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140415 11:12:30 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140415 11:12:30 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140415 11:12:30 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
140415 11:12:30 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140415 11:12:30  InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() failed with EAGAIN. Will make 5 attempts before giving up.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 1 failed.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 2 failed.
```

I've tried setting `innodb_use_native_aio = 0` in my.cnf but that doesn't fix it either. I also tried setting the following:

```
default-storage-engine=myisam 
skip_innodb
```

Still no go. I've also just tried this and no go:

```
sudo touch /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld
service mysqld start
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to run reconfigure to get it back working again. This took some time for the program to finish itself up, it also errored and said it couldn't set mysql root password.

But in the end it restarted mysql and everything came back online.

```
dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
```